# Science fiction movie featuring an octopus type alien

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to remember a sci-fi movie featuring an Octopus type alien, possibly purple, stalking the crew of a spaceship. I only remember one scene. The creature was very slow, had one eye and I think it was acidic, and possibly 6 or 7 ft tall.  I remember the crew uniforms were basically white. The film was featured once on Super Scary Saturday on TBS in the late 80s. I always assumed it was a movie from the '60s, or maybe it could be '70s. I think they had star-trek-type phasers. The monster thing basically couldn't be killed but I don't remember how the movie ended, except I believe only one or two people survive. I believe the crew had some sort of plan but were getting killed too quickly. The main character I remember resembled the first guy to die in Alien. But in this film he is the medic.

Comment: This is a nice description of the monster but can you remember anything at all that happens in the film? When did you see it? Was it new then?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Perhaps one of these? https://rottenink.wordpress.com/tag/super-scary-saturday/

Comment: FWIW, [a suggested edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/152691) added some info to that post, but can't be sure it was from the same person, so rejected. Toby, if you and Keldor are the same, you can merge the accounts by following the instructions on [this link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Please do, you'll be able to edit the question at will afterwards.

Answer (score 13):

It might be [The Green Slime](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064393/), which came out in 1968.

The white suited crew of a space station orbiting earth encounters an alien race that grow out of a green, gooey substance, with several tentacles and a single eye in the center of their forehead. They seemed to feed off of energy, so the crew's phaser-like weapons only seem to make the aliens more powerful. Their tentacles immediately electrocute anybody they come in contact with, and the ship is completely infested with the creatures within a matter of days. The crew formulates a plan to lead all of the creatures into a single section of the station and then blow it up, but the aliens regenerate too quickly and the plan fails.

At the end, the remaining crew completely abandons the station allowing it to self destruct, with the final scene being the two heroes reconciling their differences as they attempt to decide who will stay behind on the station to activate the detonator.

[image: The Green Slime poster]

Answer (score 11):

Could it be [Dragon's Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon%27s_Domain), a Space: 1999 episode? The original air date is 23 October 1975.

It features an octopus-like monster with a single brilliant eye, nearly unkillable, that ate people and spat out corroded corpses.

[image: Dragon's Domain]

([image from IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0706323/))

The Alphans' uniforms are white, and they wield handheld lasers.

I distinctly remember watching the scariest scenes from under a blanket :-)

Comment: Glowing orbs for eyes, where have I seen that before...